# Can I tessellate on the GPU with GLSL if I have OpenGL 3.0?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, tessellation

Is there any way inside of OpenGL to create vertices after the vertex array has been sent to the GPU in Opengl 3.0? I don't have access to the tessellation shaders.

Comment: Geometry shader allows you to modify your input primitive. However the purpose is different from the Tesselation one. If you're looking for tesselation on openGL 3.0, check if the ARB extension for that exists for openGL 3.0. It was approved in 2010, who knows.

Comment: Unfortunately GL_ARB_tessellation_shader came out in OpenGL 3.2

Comment: Ok, so there is a way to create vertices in between the vertex and fragent shader. As said, the Geometry shader can. However you're the judge to know if it's an appropriate solution for your problem. Could you add more details on the context of your problem ? (The approval for the Geometry shader was in 2008, year of the 3.0 release. You may be able to use this shader.)

Comment: I'm trying to tessellate my polygons in the GPU using quadtrees between the vertex and fragment shaders... and it appears that GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 (idk why there's a 4 there) came out in 3.2 also... ughhh. Is there any way I could use OpenCL?

Comment: For pure tesselation, the Geometry shader would not have been a good choice anyway. OpenCL is unknown to me. You might need to do some research on this subject before asking a new related question with the proper tags.

Comment: You can, but there are some nasty restrictions on patch size/shape due to the number of vertices you can fetch in a GS. You have to use adjacency primitive types to get enough vertices, and the largest adjacency type (triangle) only gives you enough for 6 control points per-primitive.